# Getting events from a location

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if anyone has been working with this [facebook-events-by-location](https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location-core) library, because I've tried it myself and came across 2 potential problems:

1. The result list is too short (only about 20 items)
2. Some of the events are from another country (Germany) and have nothing to do with being nearby the provided location

[image: results from call]

What would you suggest that I obtain more events, and more importantly, ones that are in the nearby location?
Is there any other library like this one, or maybe there is a simpler way to directly use the Facebook Graph API and obtain more events by location?
Extra: do you need to some sort of premium (paid) account for the Facebook Graph API in order to get more results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only search for Places by location, and then get the Events of those Places. That´s what the package actually does, if you take a look at the source or the Readme. The limit for Places is set to 100, and if there are only 20 Events in those 100 Places, you will not get more.

There is no API to get events by location, that package only a workaround. Also, there is no premium/paid account for the Graph API, it is just not possible (directly).

Comment: thanks for replying. Do you have any advice on what to do in order to get as many events as possible in a particular (only one) city? I don't care about other cities.

Comment: you would need to find as many places as possible, use paging for that. it´s explain here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging